# My integral methods are returning far too large of values

Tags: java, numeric, numerical-methods, integral, numerical-integration

So according to my math classes and various math videos on Youtube, the integral of `(1 / sqrt(2 * pi)) * exp((-x ^ 2) / 2)` from negative infinity to positive infinity is exactly 1.

So I wrote a couple methods to get 100 even width partial integrals from -3 to 3 using the trapezoid method.

```
public double integrate() {
    double[] integrateNormal = new double[100];
    double sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        double pos_a = i*6/100.00-3;
        double pos_b = ((i+1)*6/100.00)-3;

        double a = (1/(Math.sqrt(2*Math.PI)))*(Math.exp(.5*(-Math.pow(pos_a,2))));
        double b = (1/(Math.sqrt(2*Math.PI)))*(Math.exp(.5*(-Math.pow(pos_b,2))));
        double h = 0.1;

        integrateNormal[i] = (a+b)*h/2;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        sum = sum + integrateNormal[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

However, sum is returning as 1.66, not 1 or even just a little more than 1. Where is my error?

Comment: Can you more specific about the formula used here? Thanks

Comment: why did you define `h` as `0.1` ?  for `i=0`, `pos_a=-3, pos_b=-2.94`, for `i=1`, `pos_a=-2.94, pos_b=-2.88`. the step is `0.06`, not `0.1`

Comment: Why would you ever expect this to match the answer?  How are you handling the fact that the integral needs to sample the function at infinity?  Clearly at some point values are negligible but how did you decide on +/- 3?